# Display submenu when hovering but don't hide it when un-hovering

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a very simple multilevel menu, like so:

HTML:

```
<ul class="multilevel">
<li>...</li>
<li>...</li>
<li>...</li>
<li>
    <ul>
        <li>...</li>
        <li>...</li>
        <li>...</li>
    </ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
.multilevel > li {position: relative; display: inline-block}
.multilevel ul {display: none; position: absolute;}
.multilevel > li:hover ul {display: block;}
```

When un-hovering, i want the submenu to stay on and not hide. Is it possible using just CSS?
Or do i need to use jQuery (in my case). If yes, how do i use jQuery so the menu stays on when hovering with css?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it if you use `opacity` instead of `display`

```css
.multilevel > li {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block
}
.multilevel ul {
    opacity:0;
    position: absolute;
    transition:0s 100s;
}
.multilevel > li:hover ul {
    opacity:1;
    transition:0s;
}
```

```html
<ul class="multilevel">
    <li>...</li>
    <li>...</li>
    <li>...</li>
    <li>Hover
        <ul>
            <li>...</li>
            <li>...</li>
            <li>...</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

It is prolonging the hover effect i set it to 100s you can change it as you wish

Comment: @Shaggy Thanks you can change the effect to 1000s or something to make it always appear

Comment: Yeah, best to set the delay to something ridiculously high. Depending on the layout, you may also need to position the submenu off screen until it's activated, so it's not blocking any actions on items behind it.

Answer (score 1):

There are no explicit properties like mouseenter/mouseleave in CSS.You can rather use jquery mouseenter event to show the inner ul element:

```
$('.multilevel > li').mouseenter(function(){
    $(this).find('ul').show();
});
```