# Increase a div size on click with css alone

Tags: css, resize, click

I want to increase the width of my div when I click on it. I want to achieve this with CSS alone. Is it possible? I made it increase in width via hover, but I need the same effect to happen when I click on the div. Suggestions are appreciated.

**HTML**

```
<div id="sample"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
#sample{
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  background:#000000;
}
```

I want to change the width to 200px on click.

Comment: Did I misread it in the first place or did this question originally ask about increasing the height rather than the width?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One potential solution would be to add a `tabindex` attribute to the `div`, like so:

```
<div id="sample" tabindex="0"></div>
```

Now, you can use `:focus` in your CSS:

```
#sample:focus {
   width: 200px;
}
```

[Here's a jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2fvucd2e/) to show it in action.

Unfortunately, when the `div` is blurred, the width will go back. *Update: check out [Shaggy's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29730814/1028949) for a clever solution to retaining the focus effect.*

If you need the width to stay after the `div` is blurred, you will likely have to venture into JavaScript/jQuery, or just add an `onclick` attribute.

```
<div id="sample" onclick="this.style.width = '200px';"></div>
```

Comment: @AJITH If this answer solved your problem, please mark it as "accepted" (the checkbark below the vote count)

Answer (score 3):

If you'd like to toggle the size on click, you can put the `div` within a `label` after an invisible `input`:

```css
label {
  display: inline-block;
}

label input {
  display: none;
}

input:checked ~ #sample {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
}

#sample {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #000000;
}
```

```html
<label>
  <input type="checkbox">
  <div id="sample"></div>
</label>
```

Answer (score 3):

Following on from Quantastical's accepted answer, if you want the height to stay at the new size after the `div` loses focus, you can do it with a bit of trickery involving transitions with no need for JavaScript.

As Quantastical said, first give your div a `tabindex`.

```
<div id="sample" tabindex="0"></div>
```

Note, that with a value of `0`, it will become the first focused item when traversing the page with the tab button on your keyboard so you may want to increase the value so that it's focused in the right order. Alternatively, if you don't want the change to occur when the focus shifts to the `div` through tabbing, set the `tabindex` value to `-1`.

The CSS is then as follows:

```
#sample{
    background:#000;
    height:100px;
    transition:height 0s 10000s;
}
#sample:focus{
    height:200px;
    outline:0;
    transition:height 0s;
}
```

The trick is to set a `transition` on the unfocused `div` with a ridiculously high delay so that it never gets executed.

[Credit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29716634/4768433)

Comment: Clever workaround. Future visitors: a `tabindex` attribute needs to be added to the `div` in order to allow it to be focusable.

Comment: I posted this after your answer was accepted, intending it to serve as a follow-up but, you're right, for the sake of completeness, I should include the note about the `tabindex`.

Answer (score -1):

This cannot be done with CSS you need to write a couple of lines of JavaScript to archive this.

If you change your mind to write some JS here is just one solution:

```
<script> // Creating a script tag to write JS
var sampleDiv = document.getElementById('sample'); // Grabbing the sample  id

sampleDiv.addEventListener('click', function(e) { // When someone clicks on it
  sampleDiv.style.width = "200px"; // The width increases to 200px
};
</script>
```